# IPTables Internal Load Balancing

Tags: iptables, load-balancing, nat

I'm trying to setup a load balancing within the same LAN using IPTables (if possible). My idea is to emulate our main load balancer, but within a virtual environment, all the servers are virtual machines by the way.

There is a Gateway server, which forwards traffic to and from the Virtual Servers and the Real World, and I want to use that Gateway to balance some traffic within that Virtual LAN.

My setup is:

- GatewayServer -> 2 interfaces: eth0(Public), eth2(Private; 10.x.y.0/24)
- ServerA -> 1 interface: eth2(Private; 10.x.y.0/24)
- ServerB -> 1 interface: eth2(Private; 10.x.y.0/24)

On ServerB there is 2 instances of a service, listening on ports 60003 and 60004.

My goal is to be able to open a connection from ServerA to GatewayServer:60002 and get balanced to ServerB on ports 60003 and 60004 in a Round Robin fashion.

I've been able to open connections to to ServerB from ServerA through GateWay server, but the connecion always reach ServerB on port 60003, and never the other one, 60004.

I have the Gateway set up this way:

```
-A POSTROUTING -i eth2 -s 10.x.y.0/24 -p tcp --dport 60002 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.x.y.18-10.x.y.18:60003-60004

-A POSTROUTING -o eth2 -j MASQUERADE
```

Sniffing on ServerB I see the packets comming from GatewayServer, but always hiting port 60003 as stated before.

Any idea?

Comment: Please review the answers to the questions you have already asked and if applicable mark the one that was most useful as accepted. This will help the community know that the questions have useful answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to check the version of the kernel you are running as kernels later than 2.6.11-rc1 have had the functionality you want to use removed. To find your kernel version use uname e.g.

```
uname -r 
2.6.32-71.el6.x86_64
```

From the iptables man page

> In Kernels up to 2.6.10 you  can  add  several  --to-destination options.  For those kernels, if you specify more than one destination  address,  either  via  an  address  range  or  multiple --to-destination   options,  a  simple  round-robin (one  after another in cycle)  load  balancing  takes  place between  these addresses.  Later Kernels (>= 2.6.11-rc1) donât have theability to NAT to multiple ranges anymore.

Comment: I see. My kernel is 2.6.18-164.15.1.el5xen. so it seems there is nothing I can do.